# Why is variable considered undefined when called inside my function?

Tags: javascript, typeerror, console.log, uppercase

Very new to Javascript here. Can someone please explain why I receive an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property "toLowerCase" of undefined at capitalize? and again when I use console.log?

```js
let c = "this iS a String";

function capitalize(c) {
  let d = c.toLowerCase;
  return (d.charAt(0).toUpperCase + d.slice(1));
}
console.log(capitalize());
```

I have also tried expressing the function capitalize() inside a variable, but when I log the variable, I receive the function as an output, rather than the string result.

Comment: You forgot the `()` after `toLowerCase` to call the function.

Comment: Also after `toUpperCase` inside the function.

Comment: Also you should pass a parameter to `capitalize`.

Comment: So simple, thank you!

Comment: To *invoke/call* a function you need the parenthesis, even if there are no parameters.  Without them you are just referring to the function, not actually calling it..

Answer (score 1):

toLowerCase should be toLowerCase(). Also need to add c to the function call.

```
let c = "this iS a String";

function capitalize(c) {
  let d = c.toLowerCase();
  return (d.charAt(0).toUpperCase + d.slice(1));
}
console.log(capitalize(c));
```